# Regex to extract http authorization header

Tags: javascript, regex

Header looks like this:

```
TOKEN client=12345,hash=abcde
```

I need to check if the transmitted header matches this pattern and extract client and hash. Any ideas how to do this in vanilla javascript?

Comment: I have a more generic and workable solution, but it depends how flexible the solution needs to be? Do you need support for extra values or changing terms (client/hash)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
var s = 'TOKEN client=12345,hash=abcde';
var m = s.match(/TOKEN +client=([^,]*),hash=([^,]*)/);
// m => ["TOKEN client=12345,hash=abcde", "12345", "abcde"]
// use m[1] and m[2] for your values
```

OR separately:

```
var m = s.match(/client=([^,]*)/);
var client = m[1];

var m = s.match(/hash=([^,]+)/);
var hash = m[1];
```

Comment: ``String.match`` will only be useful to check if the String match but it doesn't extract values. Better using ``RegExp.exec`` method for this I think

Comment: @pomeh: check the output and extracted values in the answer

Comment: @pomeh `String.match` [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array of strings that match the regex, or `null` if none are found.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was confident that ``String.match`` returns something like ``true`` or ``false`` but it's not. Thanks for the info !

Comment: @anubhava but TOKEN has to be checked too, would s.match(/TOKEN client=([^,]*),hash=([^,]*)/) be correct?

Comment: @artworkadシ: Yes thanks, I updated.